# C# UWP - DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly not giving the same permissions (?) as DevicePairingKinds. ProvidePin

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

I want to read the HeartRateMeasurement characteristic of a ble device, this requires pairing.

The program will run on a display without a input device so I've used `ConfirmOnly` for pairing so far. This worked fine for another device that usually requires a pin.

The HeartRate device gets paired succesfully with `ConfirmOnly` but the HeartRateMeasurement characteristic remains read restricted.

When using the pin the HeartRateMeasurement characteristic becomes readable.

Why is `ConfirmOnly` acting differently than `ProvidePin`?

Would it be possible to use `ProvidePin` without user input, i.e just accepting it without checking the pin?

Comment: It is because if you use ConfirmOnly there is no authentication (pairing) actually (and encryption is disabled). So yes, you have to use more secure PIn pairing. Yes, you can provide PIN in the authentication (pairing) handler. Use CustomPairing class.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I have implemented ProvidePin but my issue is I won't be having a option to input the Pin. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You do not need any user action. Simple provide predefined PIN.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko could you elaborate what you mean by "provide predefined PIN"? The device I'm pairing displays a randomly generated pin, I need to enter this pin in the DevicePairingKind.ProvidePin handler.

Comment: It is called Passkey entering. PIN is legacy PIN pairing. There are also Passkey notification (when device sends numeric passkey to your device and you have to type it on devices keyboard) and Numeric Confirmation (which is also used in Confirm only) pairings. So your device uses Passkey Notification. Unfortunately you can not use it with your device that has no keyboard.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying .